# Rounded Border in theme for DateRangePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make the  DateRangePicker with rounded border. I am using this code below for customization but I didn't know how to make rounded border in theme for  DateRangePicker.

```
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.white,
      accentColor: Color(0xFF8BC541),
      accentTextTheme: TextTheme(
        button: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xFF8BC541),
        ),
      ),
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      ),
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
        primary: Color(0xFF8BC541),
      ),
      

    ),
```

I'm using this plugin
'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart'

Comment: Can you include an image that you like to archive?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
```

with

```
shape: new CustomRoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(20.0)),
            ),
```